# django templates displaying the html tags as it is

Tags: python, html, django

below is the index.html file inside my workspace/projectname/templates/appname

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>my news</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>look below for news</h1>
        {%if categories%}
            <ul>
                {%for category in categories%}
                    <li>{{category.name}}</li>

                {%endfor%}
            </ul>

        {%endif%}

        {%if headings%}

            <p>
                {%for heading in headings%}

                    <a href="#">{{heading.title}}</a>
                    <br>
                    {{heading.content}}

                {%endfor%}
            </p>

        {%endif%}
    </body>

</html>
```

the problem is `<ul>` and `<li>` tags are working and displaying the list as it should do.the `<a>` tag is also displaying a hyperlink,but the `<p>` tag and `<br>` tags are not being rendered and are being displayed as a text,cant think what might be the problem.i am fairly new to django.
[image: index.html]

Answer (score 5):

Try using `{{heading.content|safe}}` or turn autoescape off (See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)).

Answer (score 3):

Although, the other answer accurately solves your problem, but that approach is not safe everytime.

If you know that only trustworthy people are going to write that article/post, then you can simply turn Django's [autoescaping off](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) (as pointed in the other answer).

But if you want to display HTML from an untrustworthy source, you are prone to XSS attacks. In that case you should use applications like [django-bleach](https://django-bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It will escape specific HTML tags like `<script>` and any other tags that you want to escape.